# merge two datasets where there is a one to one correspondence

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
df1
cola colb coldc 
A    101  green
B    101  blue
C    102  green
.

df2
cold othercols
A    .
B    .
C    .
.
```

`cola` and `cold` are equivalent but named differently, they both have a one to one correspondence to a combination of `colb` and `colc`. I would like to:

```
df2
cold othercols cole
A    .         101green 
B    .         101blue
C    .         102green
.    .         .
```

combine `colb` and `colc` and then match this to `cold` on the basis of their one to one correspondence.

So far I have tried

```
df2= pd.merge(df2,
              df1,
              how='left', left_on=['cold'],right_on=['colb', 'colc'])
```

This returns a merged dataframe where all the columns recieved are `nan`
and variations of this - i am not sure pd.merge can be used here.

and also:

```
    df2['cole'] = \
    df2[['colb',
         'colc']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)

    mapping = df2.set_index('cola')['cole']

    mapping.groupby(mapping.index).first() # drop duplicates

    df1['cole'] = df1['cold'].map(mapping)
```

which return the error 
    InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Even though i removed duplicates for the mapping series.

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two different things:

1 - Merge `df1` and `df2`:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, left_on='cold', right_on='cola', how='left')
```

2 - Concat `colb` and `colc`:

```
df2['cole'] = df2['colb'].astype(str) + df2['colc'].astype(str)
```

Comment: I asked the wrong question but you answered what i asked so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can run

```py
df2['cole'] = [str(aa) + str(cc) for zip (aa, cc) in zip(df2.colb, df2.colc)]
```